# Getting started with servers / networking for an iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, network-programming

I'm developing an iOS social networking application that will involve users sharing and rating photos. I've spent about the last year or so on and off teaching myself how to develop in cocoa touch and now I'm ready to get started with the networking aspect of the app. Unfortunately, I have 0 networking / database experience and was wondering if anyone had any good advice on what things to consider and where / how to get started. In all likelihood I'm probably not going to build my own server and instead will go with something like rack space. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty abstract question.

Eventually, you're going to have to focus on a particular architecture ( which database, which network technology), but before you do that, you need to get an outline idea of what the available options are and what the strengths and weaknesses of each are.

The server database is probably the easiest, as it doesn't make such a big difference.  The choices are an sql database ( mysql, sqllite ....), not an sql database ( nosql, in memory tables) or some higher level abstraction where you can hide the differences and decide later ( core data for example).  This may be constrained by your deployment decisions, you'll have more choices of rack options if you go for LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySql, PHP) for example.  If you stick with apple kit and use a MacOS X back end, you may have additional options for network architecture ( DistributedObjects for instance.

The network architecture is also a difficult choice from a wide range of choices.  There are really dozens of options with lots of different pros and cons.  As this is your first foray into this area, I'd count ease of use and availability of help high among your priorities.  Here are a few popular technologies you might want to investigate ( in alphabetical order to minimise flammability :) ).  DistributedObjects ( apple), JAXP, JSON, RPC, SOAP, XML ( bare, without the soapy bits).

One more question you should ask yourself is "Can you get away with just a database connection, or do you need to do processing on the back end?".  If you can, you might be able to get away with just using a remote database and then you only need to learn core data ( which will still keep you busy for a long time).

Once you've decided what technologies you want to use, then you can start learning.

You mentioned using a hosted server. You'll want to be able to run a test server locally.  Fortunately almost all the worthwhile options for both database and network technology will run on any unix-like machine, so you can probably use your regular dev machine.

Also bear in mind that some of these choices are religious, so everyone you read will have strong biases ( myself definitely included).

Comment: Thanks for that long, well thought out response. I'm thinking there is a good chance that I'll be able to get away with just a database connection, not sure I understand how CoreData comes into play from what I've read. CoreData seems to be on the client side to store objects? I've read in Apple that it's not considered a database...maybe I'm not understanding it correctly though.

Comment: Core Data is a layer above the data storage, it handles the in memory objects and the interaction with the storage.  You can choose what storage method you want it to use ( database, plain files, xml etc).

Answer (score 2):

Getting started to iOS Networking application. Here are the required things:-
You really need good backend developing experience in **MySQL and complex database queries Plus experience in developing web services**. At the root you need server host for backend and Admin module as you mentioned in question like race space or any other. You need to spend some months with mysql backend,web service and admin module implementation.

For fully functional social networking app your first task will be to manage users. Log in/Sign up will be there. Every user can post his status and can comment to other user's status.All status posts or comments will have their unique id and relationships to userid's table. May be image uploading and comments on photo will also be there So there will be lots of tables and relationships between them on backend side.

For Social Networking app, amount of work will be bigger on both backend/web service side and iOS side.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Just out of curiosity, why would PHP be needed? I thought that was only for use with HTML and web pages. Also, which is meant by web services?

Comment: Also, just curious, but what about this would involve a team of developers on the back end? Just playing devils advocate...

Comment: Well, I apologize about word PHP rather it should be "PHP web service" more specifically. It's an alternative for developing web service or you can also use .net to develop web services.